# Установка последней версии Git на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, git, apt-get

Ubuntu 14.04. Устанавливаю Git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

`git --version` показывает, что установлена 1.9.0. При этом последний релиз уже 2.6.0 и я хочу установить его. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для этого есть специальный персональный архив пакетов ([PPA](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/ppa))

```
add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
apt-get update

# установить, если ещё нет
apt-get install git

# если уже установлен, то обновить
apt-get install --only-upgrade git
```

Comment: просто к слову: использование *lts*-дистрибутива и «пионерских» репозиториев типа *ppa\** выглядит, мягко говоря, несколько взаимоисключающим.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это к тому, что ОС у меня lts? Новые возможности ОС меня не очень интересуют, а вот новые возможности Git очень хочу испробовать. Так что это вопрос интересов и приоритетов. Кроме того, чем меньше багов в ОС, тем реже блокируется моя работа, так что пускай будет lts.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а разве без последней комманды
    sudo apt-get upgrade git
,git ставится не последней версии ?

Comment: @DidMazay уточнил описание, плюс сама инструкция была вообще неверная, исправил. Спасибо, что обратили внимание  )

Comment: А как тогда быть, если не хочется подключать ppa?